# How to automatically re-run a state if transition condition fails?

Tags: python, transition, fsm

Im writing screen scraping application in python, using [transitions](https://github.com/pytransitions/transitions) to handle the state machine.

The initial state is looking for a GUI window. When the window has been found, the state machine changes to next state.

[image]

Please consider the following code:

```
class ScreenScrapper(object):
    window = None

    def is_window_found(self):
        return bool(self.window)

    def state_look_for_window(self):
        window = get_window()  # Returns a bitmap object or None if window is not found
        self.do_work()

    def state_do_work(self):
        print('Do some work!')
        print('Window er: ', self.window)


states = ['dummy', 'state_look_for_window', 'state_do_work']

transitions = [
    {'trigger': 'start', 'source': 'dummy', 'dest': 'state_look_for_window', 'after': 'state_look_for_window'},
    {'trigger': 'do_work', 'source': 'state_look_for_window', 'dest': 'state_do_work', 'conditions': 'is_window_found', 'after': 'state_do_work'},
]

screen_scrapper = ScreenScrapper()
Machine(model=screen_scrapper, states=states, transitions=transitions, initial='dummy')

screen_scrapper.start()
```

In this simple example, the `start` changes states from `dummy` to `state_look_for_window`. The `after` callback will look for the window and afterwards change state to `state_do_work`. This transition has the condition `is_window_found`

**Question:** How can `state_look_for_window` be executed again as long as the transition condition `is_window_found` return `False`? Please note: I'm only interested in a solution that can be contained within the state machine. In other words, the only code outside must remain `screen_scrapper.start()`.

Comment: shouldn't `while not is_window_found` work ?

Comment: I've thought about that solution, and it would work. But the transition library uses conditions very actively, so I suspect there must be a better and more correct way to do it, especially because this use case is very common.

Answer (score 0):

Since you just need to transition from one state to another you can just do a state transition after checking `is_window_found`

I think it should look like this

```
    def state_look_for_window(self):
    if not is_window_found:
        self.state_look_for_window() 
    else:
        window = get_window()  # Returns a bitmap object or None if window is not found
        self.do_work()
```

Comment: That was exactly my first approach. But it returns the following error:
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded

Comment: i am not sure how this state thing works. probably add another trigger that transitions from your state to the same state. and then call the trigger instead of the method itself. Because the standard recursion depth of python is not very deep.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking for a 'reflexive transition', which is a trigger having the same State as source and destination.
I would replace your current diagram by another State called 'Window Ready', and specify an internal transition for that state, where you remain cycling inside the same, until the desired Window GUI is found.